# in vi, how to search and append something?

Tags: regex, vi

I have a bash file

```
#!/bin/bash
curl '/entry/point.json?name=ab'
echo 1
sleep 60
curl '/entry/point.json?name=bc'
echo 2
sleep 60
```

and so on.
I'd like to append

```
|jsonpp
```

after each curl command. How am I supposed to do that in VI? Such as

> :%s/curl/?????/g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. `:global`

```
:g/curl/norm A|jsonpp
```

would be my favourite

---

### 2. 'interactive' repeats:

- 'Highlight' `curl` (using `*` or `#`)
- <kbd>A</kbd>`|jsonpp`<kbd>Esc</kbd>
- repeat at leisure: <kbd>n</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>   <kbd>n</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>   <kbd>n</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>   ...

---

### 3. bash functions

Alternatively,

```
#!/bin/bash
function curl()
{
    /usr/bin/curl "$@" | jsonpp
}

curl '/entry/point.json?name=ab'
echo 1
sleep 60
curl '/entry/point.json?name=bc'
echo 2
sleep 60
```

Comment: @Kent It's more specific, but carries the burden of having to type it :/ From the OP's sample and command I see that this is not necessary and also not his question. I would add other magic, but then I'd have to remove my recommendation: "... _would be my favourite_" :)

Comment: This is so working! Would you mind pointing to me some resources to learn the "norm" ?

Comment: @galaapples that'd be **[`:help :norm`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#:normal)**

Answer (score 0):

```
:%s/^\(curl .*\)$/\1 | jsonpp/g
```